# How mantain images in my .apk

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

I I'm developing an Android application. When I run the application from Eclipse development enviroment it works good, but, if I install manually the .apk generate in \bin folder, I lost all images that I put in \res folder (drawable-hdpi, drawable-hdpi, etc). Why?

Comment: Just curious: did you use the same device for both operations?

Comment: What do you mean 'lost all images'? What specifically is the code your using to access the images (that isn't working now that you have manually installed)? What is the logcat output when the images don't load?
We need more information to help you.

Comment: Yes, @Chris, I use two different device for the operations

Comment: If the devices have different resolutions, they pick the images out of different folders. Do you have folders which match the resolution of both devices? More infos over here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: No my devices have the same resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new folder **drawable** in **res** and try putting images in that folder